# what is the layout folder for samsung galaxy s4?

Tags: android

I am search about samsung galaxy s4 layout design from google and many website .

following steps i am used to create emulator

[image]

at design time following screen appear

[image]

and run time following screen appear

[image]

I am creating layout folder - layout-large-xxhdpi .
please help me ,which type of layout folder create then display layout at design time ,same as runtime .

Comment: make folder name as layout-sw360dp then put your code in it

Comment: @AvinashKumarPankaj display following message in command line window Large Screen, XX-High Density' is not a best match for any device/locale combination.

Comment: clean your code and run it again

Answer (score 0):

you can use layout-sw480dp folder

Comment: Thanks your feedback, but i have not enough reputation for comment.

Answer (score -2):

sorry,My English is so poor. The meaning of this passage is that: Don't need to creat the layout-large-xxhdpi folder, please use the dip for design layout, 1080p is 360dip on the width,720p is also 360dip on the width.the 1080p resolution alone if you need to provide high-definition pictures, please in the drawable-xxhdpi.